In Excel, is it possible to copy just the cell color from conditional formatting from one tab to another?
I am working with golf scores. On my first tab, I have the score card which includes the hole numbers, par for the hole and each player's score for each hole. Down below, I have created another score card to calculate par. I have included conditional formatting for the calculated par to highlight based on their score. For instance, a -1 will be green and a +1 will be purple.
On another tab I have the final running score for each player. I want to take the cell highlighting results from tab one and copy it to the running score for the player on tab 2. For instance, if player A gets a birdie on hole 3, I want the green formatting from that hole for that player to copy over to their running score on the other tab.
I have tried using the format painter, but it is also copying the conditional formatting rules to the other cells and I only want the color of the cell copied from one tab to the other. Is this possible?

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with format painter you would need VBA here.

I am not knowledgeable with VBA, so what I am trying to accomplish may not be possible.

You can wait may be someone will try to help. Also try to research and do some googling there is a solution to your question using VBA.(Hint) Search with the same keywords, you will get it in the fifth or sixth search option possibly.

This solution seems viable, with some altering to the code (mainly the ranges). Let me know if you think it fits, I can try if you tell us your ranges.

Or this one give it a proper search and I'm sure you'll get there. If you found something but it won't work, come back to us with whatever you found.

I just used format painter for copying conditional formatting and I can confirm that this is working.
However, you might take into consideration that the conditional formatting might be based on values in other cells (imagine it's based on cell "A1"). When using the format painter to copy the conditional formatting, this will be done, and indeed that new conditional formatting will also be based on "A1", but it will be based on cell "A1" of that new sheet.
Are you sure your conditional formatting rules are referring to the cells you want to refer to?

I think OP just wants the colours, not the conditional formatting. (I'm not sure why though.)

@Excellor: in that case, his or her reaction might be to edit the question, adding some examples, in order better to explain the situation.
